# Git push to svn keep as multiple commits

Tags: git, git-svn, smartgit

I would like to know if there any way to push multiple commits from local Git repository to remote SVN repository and do not merge them into one single commit?

I am using SmartGit and let's say I have 5 commits in my local GIT branch, this branch referenced to remote SVN /trunk, when push those commits to SVN I get one big commit in SVN

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: I am using SmartGit GUI client, will 'git svn dcommit' solve my problem?

Comment: I don't know how gui client works but git svn command to make it is that, try if that will help you.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. I use SmartGit for SVN, and when I press 'Push' it pushes 1 SVN commit per 1 Git commit... Maybe you have 5 commits in an anonymous Git branch, that is not translated to SVN. In this case you should name a branch for the anonymous branches and push it first.

Comment: What do mean be anonymous branch? My workflow is looks like as: 1. Create local git branch "X". 2. Make let's say 4 commits in local branch "X" 3. Merge local git branch "X" to main git branch, which is linked to svn trunk. 4. Pull from SVN repository 5. Push to SVN repository. After item 5. I get 1 revision in SVN repository "Merged from branch'X'"

Comment: @iKiR that's exactly the problem: in the main git branch (let's call it `trunk`) you just have one "merge" commit, the 5 merge source commits can't be pushed as SVN does not support multiple lines of history in one branch. Hence, instead of **merging** branch `X `to `trunk`, **Rebase** your five commits onto `trunk`, so you just have a linear history.

Answer (score 1):

From your additional comments, it sounds like the problem is your merge.  I recommend reading the `git merge` documentation, particularly the section on "fast-forward merges".  It sounds like your client is doing a "no-ff" merge, which combines the commits on branch X into a single merge commit on your main branch.  When you push to SVN it's that single merge commit that's being pushed across.

What you want is a fast-forward merge.  From the command-line you can ensure you get this by using `git merge --ff-only`.   I'm not familiar with SmartGit, but from the docs it looks like it offers you this option when you request a merge: http://www.syntevo.com/smartgithg/documentation.html?page=commands-branch#merge